# Concatenar una variable de PHP en HTML

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente Div, el cual es parte de una td:

```
<td class='text-center'> <div style='height: 35px; width: 35px; background-color:red; border-radius: 20px;'> </div> </td>
```

Lo que sucede es que el background-color lo quiero poner según la base de datos, la variable en la cual va el color en hexadecimal es $result['hexcolor'], y no se como concatenarla ahí en el div. El codigo completo de la td es el siguiente:

```
echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='text-center'>".$result['id']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'> <div style='height: 35px; width: 35px; background-color:red; border-radius: 20px;'> </div> </td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$result['reference']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>
                <figure class='block-4-image mx-auto d-block' style='height:30px; width:50px;'>
                    <img src='".$result['image']."' alt=".$result['reference']." class='img-fluid'>
                </figure>
            </td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$result['stock']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$result['purchases']."</td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$state."</td>
            <td>
                <input type='button' name='btnEditarProduct' value='Editar' class='btn btn-outline-dark editProductSpecify' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$result['id']."' data-color='".$result['hexcolor']."' data-reference='".$result['reference']."' data-stock='".$result['stock']."' data-status='".$result['status']."' data-imagen='".$result['image']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editSpecify'>
                <input type='button' name='' value='Eliminar' class='btn btn-outline-dark btnEliminar' data-id='".$result['id']."'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ";
```

Como veis, es un archivo php que me retorna una tabla, espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro del `echo` puedes concatenar para incluir la variable `php` que quieras.

```
echo "....
<td class='text-center'> <div style='height: 35px; width: 35px; background-color:".$result['hexcolor']."; border-radius: 20px;'> </div> </td>
...";
```